# Install Specific Node.JS version on ubuntu, aws ami

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I want to install
NODEJS 14.15.1 (includes npm 6.14.8)

on Ubuntu AWS AMI.
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Answer (score 2):

Use [n](https://github.com/tj/n), an extremely simple Node version manager. that Interactively Manage Your Node.js Versions

```
sudo npm install -g n  # install n globally

n 14.15.1 #Install Node Versions and use
```